# Error : Resource temporarily unavailable Unable to receive serial data

Tags: c, usb, uart

My C code is sending data to Uart perfectly but while receiving it gives error.
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>   
void main()
{
int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY  );       
struct termios tty;
struct termios tty_old;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
/* Error Handling */

if ( USB < 0 )
{
printf( "Error %d form tcgetattr : %s /n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
}

/* Save old tty parameters */
tty_old = tty;

/* Set Baud Rate */
cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

/* Setting other Port Stuff */
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  1;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

/* Make raw */
cfmakeraw(&tty);

/* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );
if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0) 
{
printf("Error %d from tcsetattr /n",errno);
//   std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << std::endl;
}

/*  WRITE  */  
unsigned char cmd[] = "YES this program is writing \r";
int n_written = 0,spot = 0;
do {
n_written = write( USB, &cmd[spot], 1 );
spot += n_written;
} while (cmd[spot-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);

/* READ   */
int n = 0,spot_r =0;
char buf = '\0';

/* Whole response*/
char response[1024];
memset(response, '\0', sizeof response);

do {
n = read( USB, &buf, 1 );
sprintf( &response[spot_r], "%c", buf );
spot_r += n;
} while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);

if (n < 0) {
printf("Error reading %s",strerror(errno));
}
  else if (n==0) {
  printf("read nothing");
  }
  else {
  printf("Response %s",response);
  }
}
```

Error Message

```
Error reading Resource temporarily unavailable
```

It is sending data to UART perfectly.
But at reception side it gives error of resource temporary unavailable.
Should i put delay in-between? 
Or any other function that could help me out.

Thank you.

Abhi

Comment: You have opened the device for *nonblocking* mode by redundantly specifying both **O_NONBLOCK** and **O_NDELAY**. If the data are not already available for reading, you've told the system that you don't want to wait for it.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)


and
[Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  Since you don't know how to use nonblocking I/O (and don't need it), then remove the **O_NONBLOCK** and **O_NDELAY** options from the open call.

Comment: @sawdust but I am continously sending data over my UART with other system before executing this program. So still i have to remove `O_NONBLOCK` and `O_NDELAY`?

Comment: Yes.  Also you should not be using raw mode.  Your program  should be using blocking canonical **read()** for the full line (in the buffer) instead of a char at a time.

Comment: @sawdust I have removed both parameters. And my receiving data is continuous string. But still problem persists.

Comment: Add your revised code to your post for review.

Comment: @sawdust I have  revised the line by `int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);` this as you have mentioned. But still it is not showing any string on the terminal display. Though now it shows blank space instead of my error previously.

Comment: Now that it's a blocked read, the VMIN and VTIME feature has kicked in. As I already commented, your program should be using a canonical blocked read for a full line of text (instead of the raw mode of just one char at a time) (since there's a read loop looking/waiting for a CR char), . Read the links I mentioned, and rewrite your program.

Comment: @sawdust`int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR|O_NDELAY);` has been reverted. I am little bit confused whether I should go for `canonical` or `Non-canonical` processing? i want to receive the byte steam those are received from the customized board to my PC. Help me out with this.